# Django How To remove the password field from the UserCreationForm

Tags: django, passwords

I want to learn somethings about User Authentication.. I want to import UserCreationForm to my forms.py without "password field" and then I want to make password field and control by myself. How can I exclude "password fields"? thanks for help.

Answer (score 15):

Just delete them in `__init__` and update methods where they are used:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(MyUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       del self.fields['password1']
       del self.fields['password2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to hide them from the form:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = None # Standard django password input
    password2 = None # Standard django password confirmation input
```

EDIT:
Actually this is only hiding the form, but you will have problems during form validation.
Still looking for a solution.

Comment: What I did to pass the form validation is:

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.clean_password